# Slider thumb easier to grab on tactile devices

Tags: jquery, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I am using Bootstrap sliders, but the thumb feels kind of hard to grab on tactile devices even though I made it pretty big.

```
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
-webkit-appearance: none !important;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
background-color: #ECECEC;
border-radius: 30px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #3c6d59;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
border: none;
padding: 15px;
}
```

I tried to create to add padding but it doesn't change the feeling. I also tried to create an invisible div around the thumb but I was unsuccessful.

Open to any suggestions,
Cheers!

Comment: Did you try CSS transform property?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made the slider button bigger:

```
transform:scale(2);
```

The above code makes the slider button *2 times* bigger.

[JSFiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/o3pfgy3c/)

Comment: This actually changes the size of the thumb itself, which I do not want as they are already pretty big. I would like to extend the clickable area to make them easier to grab without changing the appearance

Comment: By the _clickable area_, do you mean the gray line?

Comment: No the round thumb, on mobile devices it is sometimes hard to grab it even if its big